# How to mark the first instance of each string in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of extracted forum posts, and I need to differentiate the initial post from the replies. Ideally this would be done in the form of creating a new column where a 1 represents the first instance of each thread_name, and then each of the following posts with a matching string in the thread_name column would be represented by a number counting up from one.

My data frame looks something like this:

| user_name | thread_name | post_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user 1 | thread 1 | .... |
| user 2 | thread 1 | ..... |
| user 3 | thread 1 | .... |
| user 4 | thread 2 | .... |
| user 5 | thread 2 | .... |
| user 6 | thread 2 | .... |
| user 7 | thread 2 | .... |

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) over grouping by `thread_name`:

```py
df['post_number'] = df.groupby('thread_name').cumcount() + 1
```